# how to use urlopen for dynamic query string

Tags: python, pysolr

I am working with python and solr and load the data from solr to python through url as:

```
connection = urlopen('http://localhost:8983/solr/data/select?indent=on&q=sender_name:*AX*%20AND%20message:*Avail%20Lmt&rows=211&start=0&wt=json')
```

if i have to pass different parameters in query parameter of different form  using function.How can we pass as this query is of solr

```
sender_name:*SDI* - message:*Take this* (rows = 213 start=0)
sender_name:*TRY* - message:*Look Up*   (rows =300 start=0)
```

Comment: You can use string formatting here the same as with any other string, like `urlopen(f'http://localhost:8983/solr/data/select?indent=on&q=sender_name:{sender_name}%20AND%20message:{message}%20Lmt&rows={rows}&start={tart}&wt=json')`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the functions in `urllib` (although it's easier with `requests`) to build the query string out of a dict. (Although you'll still need some string formatting to deal with the `sender_name` and `message` if those are in separate local variables, because they get crammed into the same query variable.)

Comment: @abarnert how we pass these parameter

Comment: If you’re using Python 3.6 or later, you don’t have to explicitly pass anything. That’s the point of f-strings: they can just pick up your local variables. If you’re using 2.7 or 3.5, you need to call the format method, like `'blah blah {} stuff {}'.format(firstvar, secondvar)`. Read the tutorial on strings; it will explain things much better than I can do in a comment.

Comment: @abarnert if we have to use 3 parameter or 4 parameter then it will not work.Because we have different number of parameter like 2,3,4 or more

Comment: Well, yes, you need to know what variables you're using to use those variables. I don't know what else you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this would be done by holding all of your parameters in a dictionary and then using [`urllib.parse.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode#urllib.parse.urlencode) to convert it into a suitable URL. For example:

```
import urllib

sender_name = '*AX*'
message = '*Avail Lmt'

parms = {'q' : f'sender_name:{sender_name} - message:{message}', 'rows' : 213, 'start' : 0}
url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/data/select?indent=on&' + urllib.parse.urlencode(parms, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote, safe='*:')
print(url)
```

This would give you:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/data/select?indent=on&q=sender_name:*AX*%20-%20message:*Avail%20Lmt&rows=213&start=0
```

`urllib.parse.quote()` is used to give `%20` for a space rather than `+`.

Comment: You could try adding `quote_via=urllib.parse.quote` as a parameter to `urlencode()` to force the use of `%20` for spaces.

Comment: if there is request such that  sender_name:*SDI* -message:*Take this* .Actually it is giving error in this method

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the expected URL for such a request?

Comment: It is difficult to see what variables you need. One takes `AND` and another takes `-`?  The `sender_name` and `message` variables could be included separately. Also your valid URL appears to be ok with taking `*` and `:` so I have allowed these.